# Can Veeam "Copy Job" handle alternating destinations?

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, veeam

We use Veeam 9.5 for backing up an ESX farm.

For the Copy Job we plan to switch over from USB devices to NAS with network share, like:

```
\\thenas01\VeeamCopy
\\thenas02\VeeamCopy
\\thenas03\VeeamCopy
```

The NAS will be changed periodically.
At a time only one NAS will be connected to the network.

We could configure three Copy Jobs but will get failed errors for the two missing NAS.

**Question:**
Is there a way co configure a single Copy Job which supports this constallation without reporting errors for the missing NAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test this constellation right now, but what should work:

1. Configure a DNS entry that points to all three NAS:

   ```
   thenas -> thenas01,thenas02,thenas03
   ```

   (Alternatively: give all three NAS the same IP/DNS configuration and make sure you only have one connected at a time.)
2. Configure `thenas` as a backup Repository.
   Under `Repository`-> `Advanced...` tick `This repository is backed by rotated hard drives`.
   [image]
3. Configure the backup job with `thenas` as the target

That way the backup job should only see one target and missing backup files should not be a problem.

More information on [Backup Repositories with rotated hard drives](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_repository_rotated.html?ver=95).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You have to create the repository with the `This repository is backed up by rotated hard drives` advanced option. Note that this will do a full backup for each NAS which doesn't have the current `.vbk` full backup file, so you will get 3 full backups per cycle, rather than one, and that your retention policy will count across all of the NAS's, so if you choose to retain 14 backups, it will be the 14 across all 3 of them (= 14 days if you do daily backups), rather than 14 on each (= 3 x 14 = 42 days if you do daily backups).

See [Backup Repositories with Rotated Drives | Veeam Backup Guide](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_repository_rotated.html?ver=95) for full details.